# ERROR: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (isValid() returned false)

Tags: java, hibernate, junit

What is the problem? I Use H2 DATABASE

Someone have a solution for my problem ? 
I Use H2 DATA BASE, Hibernate 5

This hy HibernateConfig.java

```
package com.train.shoponlinebackend.config;
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.train.shoponlinebackend.dto"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfig {

private static String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/onlineshopping";
private static String DATABASE_DRIVER = "org.h2.Driver";
private static String DATABASE_DIALECT = "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect";
private static String DATABASE_USERNAME = "sa";
private static String DATABASE_PASSWORD = "";
@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() {

    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(DATABASE_DRIVER);
    dataSource.setUrl(DATABASE_URL);
    dataSource.setUsername(DATABASE_USERNAME);
    dataSource.setPassword(DATABASE_PASSWORD);

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);

    builder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
    builder.scanPackages("com.train.shoponlinebackend.dto");

    return builder.buildSessionFactory();
}

private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", DATABASE_DIALECT);
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);

    return properties;
}

@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);

    return transactionManager;
}
```

}

My method in DAO IMPL :

```
@Repository("categoryDAO")
public class CategoryDAOImpl implements CategoryDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    @Override
        @Transactional
        public boolean add(Category category) {
            try {
                // add category
                sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(category);
                return true;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }
}
```

My JUNIT Test

```
@Test
    public void testAdCategory(){
        category = new Category();
        category.setActive(true);
        category.setDescription("This is some description of TV");
        category.setImageURL("CAT_1.png");
        category.setName("Television");

        assertEquals("Success added category", true, categoryDAO.add(category));
    }
```

My Error when running my junit test :

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:542)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:447)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.add(Unknown Source)
    at com.train.shoponlinebackend.test.CategoryTestCase.testAdCategory(CategoryTestCase.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:514)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:448)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (isValid() returned false)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2294)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2039)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1533)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:99)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: isValid() returned false
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:284)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:357)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2307)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2290)
    ... 40 more
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the version of h2 in your pom.xml file.

If the h2 database engine is 1.4.194, then the dependency you are adding through maven or gradle for h2 database driver should be also 1.4.194.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to restate the root cause (and solution) since you will run into this issue every time you want to use H2.  The cause is so simple and so obvious..

After you install H2 and get a working connect, go and check the precise version of the H2 bin Jar (the one with the main class) you installed (again — at the H2 server location not your program).  Here is what I am using (this month..):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\H2\bin\h2-1.4.195.jar
```

Of course your H2 server could be on another platform or location..

Rule:  When you setup your class path (i.e. your maven POM file for the a project) **always specify the EXACT same H2 jar file in your program as the one used by your H2 server ** (i.e the one above for me).  H2 is extremely finicky on this.

A maven user might have this specified in their POM file:

```
<!-- H2 DATABASE -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.193</version> <!-- Does not match the server jar -->
</dependency>
```

See the "193"?  That is different the server (see jar above) above (using 195).

Changing the pom to use 195 will fix the issue (substitute whatever version of H2 you are using here)

```
    <!-- H2 DATABASE -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.195</version> <!-- Matches the server JAR -->
    </dependency>
```

If you get frustrated or can't get to a maven repository, just copy the H2 installed server jar file (outside your project) above into your project (outside of maven) and move on..