# Unable to obtain JDBC connection caused by the Schema

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, h2

I'm trying to create a database using Hibernate + Spring + H2, everything is OK but when I launch my app, it's telling me:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [com/silho/giflib/configuration/DataConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to obtain JDBC Connection
```

so I tried to search what's the problem, actually when I remove this line from the config file, it's working but not table is created of course :

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

Can't figure out what's going on. I post some classes and files to better understanding.

```
@Configuration
public class DataConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean(){
        Resource config = new ClassPathResource("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setConfigLocation(config);
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("giflib.entity.package"));
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("giflib.db.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("giflib.db.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("giflib.db.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("giflib.db.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

The hibernate config file :

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Set naming strategy -->
        <property name="hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy">org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl</property>

        <!-- Update the database schema (structure) on startup -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

And the app properties file :

***`giflib.entity.package = com.silho.giflib.model`***

```
# Details for our datasource
giflib.db.driver = org.h2.Driver
giflib.db.url = jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/IdeaProjects/HelpCoin/data/hpcoin
giflib.db.username = samuel
giflib.db.password =
```

And the stacktrace :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [com/silho/giflib/configuration/DataConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to obtain JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:742) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at com.silho.giflib.Application.main(Application.java:11) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to obtain JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.AbstractJdbcConnectionContextImpl.getConnection(AbstractJdbcConnectionContextImpl.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.jdbcStatement(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:50) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:370) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416) ~[spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:401) ~[spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (isValid() returned false)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2293) ~[tomcat-dbcp-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2038) ~[tomcat-dbcp-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1532) ~[tomcat-dbcp-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.AbstractJdbcConnectionContextImpl.getConnection(AbstractJdbcConnectionContextImpl.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: isValid() returned false
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:283) ~[tomcat-dbcp-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:356) ~[tomcat-dbcp-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2306) ~[tomcat-dbcp-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2289) ~[tomcat-dbcp-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any more detail further down in the stack trace?  My first two thoughts - are there existing tables for any of your entities, and does the user that your app uses have permissions to create tables?  What happens if you use 'validate' instead of 'create' for hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto?

Comment: Yes, i added the log !

Comment: *try to add dialect* : 
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:~/databaseName
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

Comment: This might help.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521746/error-cannot-create-poolableconnectionfactory-isvalid-returned-false

Comment: You're a life saver Riaan Nel !! Thank you !!