# How to fix java.sql.SQLException: isValid() returned false

Tags: java, spring

I get the problem about pool connection.
A build ap AIP on server. If it's long time no request sent to my app (about `2h`), I send a new request my app. I get the problem like this:

```
DEBUG o.a.c.d.PoolableConnectionFactory - Failed to validate a poolable connection.
java.sql.SQLException: isValid() returned false
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:283)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:362)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:347).
```

I had fix this problem as [ERROR: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (isValid() returned false)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521746/error-cannot-create-poolableconnectionfactory-isvalid-returned-false?newreg=5dd2314396474c4cac5d8fcff46268d2). But not done.

My properties config:

```
spring.datasource.dbcp2.initial-size=7
spring.datasource.dbcp2.max-total=20
spring.datasource.dbcp2.pool-prepared-statements=true
spring.datasource.test-while-idle = true
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.validation-query = SELECT 1
spring.datasource.time-between-eviction-runs-millis = 60000
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=60000
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=180000
```

Please help me.

Comment: spring.datasource.dbcp2.initial-size=7
spring.datasource.dbcp2.max-total=20
spring.datasource.dbcp2.pool-prepared-statements=true
spring.datasource.test-while-idle = true
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.validation-query = SELECT 1
spring.datasource.time-between-eviction-runs-millis = 60000
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=60000
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=180000

Comment: Why do you have configuration for both Hikari and DBCP2? From the error message, DBCP2 is being used.

Comment: I had removed some like code Hikari or DBCP2. but still same error. please help me config  properties file.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a validation query in your configuration.

```
hikari.testOnBorrow=true
hikari.validationQuery=SELECT 1
```

Comment: U mean:                                                         
 spring.datasource.hikari.testOnBorrow=true </br>
spring.datasource.hikari.validationQuery=SELECT 1